# How to check siteminder status using c#

Tags: siteminder

hi I need to check the status of siteminder to see if its down or not. My current solution is to ping the policy servers of siteminder on a specified environment. Is there any way to check if Siteminder is up or down using c#? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have this code dumped into a google doc from when i was on a project that used siteminder a while back.  hope that it helps

```
String urltest = "https://domain/authentication.fcc?target=https://domain/desired/stats/page.asp";

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urltest);
CredentialCache MyCredentialCache = new CredentialCache();
MyCredentialCache.Add(new Uri(uriTeste), "NTLM", new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain"));

req.Credentials = MyCredentialCache;
req.PreAuthenticate = false;
req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
req.UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing = true;
req.Method = "POST";
req.Timeout = 100000;

HttpWebResponse rsp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```

Comment: where did you get the value of uriTeste?

Comment: Sorry about that,  uriTeste is just the url to test   www.yoursite.com , so an example is                                                          CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();

myCache.Add(new Uri("http://www.contoso.com/"),"Basic",new NetworkCredential(UserName,SecurelyStoredPassword));
myCache.Add(new Uri("http://www.contoso.com/"),"Digest", new NetworkCredential(UserName,SecurelyStoredPassword,Domain));

wReq.Credentials = myCache;

Comment: Welcome, just tinker with HttpWebResponse and HttpWebRequest and you should get some results.

Comment: Hi Tom. Client does not approve this solution. They want another approach :(